Design-Based Research and Design Thinking: are they the same thing?
Is there a difference between design-based research and design thinking? I was introduced to the idea of DT in a start-up scenario. The experience led me to DBR. Sometimes I think they are doing the samething but the terms are for different audiences. Does anyone have an thoughts, please?

Design thinking focuses on the human-centered creation and evaluation of tangible artifacts. The result is a series of physical prototypes, such as new hardware gadgets, user interfaces, and mobile applications.
DBR on the other hand provides clear, consistent definitions and guidelines for the research process. The defining feature of DBR lies within the construction of new and innovative artifacts that solve relevant design problems. This results in presentation of new concepts and approaches to enhance the knowledge base.
Maybe you have gone through this, but this seems very relevant to what you are asking.

No, I never came across it! Interesting that it positions DT as a method within a DBR methodology
